# SignalR ObjC wrapping response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, signalr

I am working on an application that uses SignalR-ObjC. I have set up the connection to our server and am receiving the correct data, but the response object is throwing me off. I am trying to parse the response to JSON and then a dictionary, but it looks like SignalR-ObjC is wrapping the response in extra data that is preventing me from parsing it to JSON.

This is what a slice of my response looks like:

```
RESPONSE: {
    A =     (
        "{\"NotificationType\":1,\"TelemetryDetails\":{\"serialNumber\":\"xxx\",\"name\":\"xxx\",,\"protectedDeviceIp\":\"xxx\"},{\"endpoint\":\"xxx\",\"ip\":\"xxx\",\"domain\":null,\"latitude\":null,\"longitude\":null,\"protectedDeviceId\":\"xxx\",\"protectedDeviceIp\":\"xxx\"}]}]},\"CommandResult\":null,\"FortressBoxSerialNumber\":\"xxx\"}"
    );
    H = NotificationsHub;
    M = notificationData;
}
```

On all other platforms, my response is only what the value for "A" is here. Not sure why SignalR-ObjC is wrapping the response with all this extra data (hub information).

My code:

```
-(void)SignalR{

    WebServices *services = [[WebServices alloc] init];

    SRHubConnection *hubConnection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURLString:@"xxx"];

    SRHubProxy *proxy = [hubConnection createHubProxy:@"xxx"];

    [services callGetSRAlertGroupNames:^(NSMutableArray *alertGroupNameArray){
        NSLog(@"SR ALERT GROUP NAMES: %@", alertGroupNameArray);

        [services callGetSRNotificationGroupNames:^(NSMutableArray *notificationGroupNameArray) {
            NSLog(@"SR NOTIFICATION GROUP NAMES: %@", notificationGroupNameArray);

            NSArray *combinedArray=[alertGroupNameArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:notificationGroupNameArray];

            // Register for connection lifecycle events
            [hubConnection setStarted:^{

                NSLog(@"Connection Started");

                for (NSString *groupName in combinedArray ){
                    [proxy invoke:@"Subscribe" withArgs:@[groupName] completionHandler:nil];
                }

            }];
            [hubConnection setReceived:^(NSString *strData) {

                NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", strData);

                NSError *jsonError;
                NSData *objectData = [strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                       error:&jsonError];

                NSLog(@"JSON DATA - %@", json);

            }];
            [hubConnection setConnectionSlow:^{
                NSLog(@"Connection Slow");
            }];
            [hubConnection setReconnecting:^{
                NSLog(@"Connection Reconnecting");
            }];
            [hubConnection setReconnected:^{
                NSLog(@"Connection Reconnected");
            }];
            [hubConnection setClosed:^{
                NSLog(@"Connection Closed");
            }];
            [hubConnection setError:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Connection Error %@",error);
            }];

            [hubConnection start];

        }];
    }];
}
```

If I copy and paste the value from "A" in my response object into where "strData" is being encoded, the code to parse it works fine. However if I pass the whole response object, it breaks.

Bearing in mind my response objects looks to be a string, how can I extract the value for "A" or stop SignalR-ObjC from wrapping my response with this extra data?

Comment: Please post most code, how do you receive that envelope? I use the following code and receive the NSDictionar with envelope:

    _hubConnection = [[SRHubConnection alloc] initWithURLString:url useDefault:YES];
    _hubProxy = [_hubConnection createHubProxy:@"SomeHub"];
    [_hubProxy on:@"ReceiveEnvelope" perform:self selector:@selector(onReceiveEnvelope:)];

Comment: More code added @NickolayOlshevsky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem by changing the hubConnection setReceived to the following:

```
  [hubConnection setReceived:^(NSDictionary *strData) {

      NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", [strData valueForKey:@"A"]);

      NSString *str = [strData valueForKey:@"A"][0];

      NSError *jsonError;
      NSData *objectData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                       error:&jsonError];

      NSLog(@"JSON DATA - %@", json);

   }];
```

What resolved the problem was changing the response object type from a NSString to a NSDictionary, then realized taking the valueForKey of "A" gave me an array so I had to get the first value in that array before encoding / serializing it.